# ObjectDataSource connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm trying to work through Pluralsights ASP.NET Webforms (c#) demos and cannot figure out why my class in my app_code folder will not show in my ObjectDataSource dropdown list when trying to create a new Datasource connection. I've been stuck on this for nearly a week and a half and am new to programming so don't understand all of the lingo after searching for helpful documents. I don't know where to implement what.

Here's the code for my BAL.cs class located in my App_Code Folder and I have a Data folder with a Linq to class connection named Northwind.

```
// Here is my code for BAL.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Globalization;
using Northwind;
 public class BAL
{
    public List<String> GetCountries()
    {
        using (var context = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.Customers
                    select c.Country).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
    {
        using (var context = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.Customers
                    where c.Country == country
                    select c).ToList();
        }
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(string custID)
    {
        using (var context = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.Customers
                    where c.CustomerID == custID
                    select c).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now the designer.cs for my Northwind.dbml file

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Northwind
{
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;


[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Northwind")]
public partial class NorthwindDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{

    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new 
   AttributeMappingSource();

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnCreated();
partial void InsertCustomer(Customer instance);
partial void UpdateCustomer(Customer instance);
partial void DeleteCustomer(Customer instance);
#endregion

    public NorthwindDataContext() : 
            base
    (global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
   ["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthwindDataContext(string connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthwindDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthwindDataContext(string connection, 
   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public NorthwindDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, 
  System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Customer>();
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Customers")]
public partial class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new 
      PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private string _CustomerID;

    private string _CompanyName;

    private string _ContactName;

    private string _ContactTitle;

    private string _Address;

    private string _City;

    private string _Region;

    private string _PostalCode;

    private string _Country;

    private string _Phone;

    private string _Fax;

    private string _Image;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnCustomerIDChanging(string value);
partial void OnCustomerIDChanged();
partial void OnCompanyNameChanging(string value);
partial void OnCompanyNameChanged();
partial void OnContactNameChanging(string value);
partial void OnContactNameChanged();
partial void OnContactTitleChanging(string value);
partial void OnContactTitleChanged();
partial void OnAddressChanging(string value);
partial void OnAddressChanged();
partial void OnCityChanging(string value);
partial void OnCityChanged();
partial void OnRegionChanging(string value);
partial void OnRegionChanged();
partial void OnPostalCodeChanging(string value);
partial void OnPostalCodeChanged();
partial void OnCountryChanging(string value);
partial void OnCountryChanged();
partial void OnPhoneChanging(string value);
partial void OnPhoneChanged();
partial void OnFaxChanging(string value);
partial void OnFaxChanged();
partial void OnImageChanging(string value);
partial void OnImageChanged();
#endregion

    public Customer()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_CustomerID", 
      DbType="NChar(5) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false, IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public string CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CustomerID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._CustomerID != value))
            {
                this.OnCustomerIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._CustomerID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("CustomerID");
                this.OnCustomerIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_CompanyName", 
    DbType="NVarChar(40) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string CompanyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CompanyName;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._CompanyName != value))
            {
                this.OnCompanyNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._CompanyName = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("CompanyName");
                this.OnCompanyNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ContactName", 
   DbType="NVarChar(30)")]
    public string ContactName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ContactName;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ContactName != value))
            {
                this.OnContactNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ContactName = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ContactName");
                this.OnContactNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ContactTitle", 
  DbType="NVarChar(30)")]
    public string ContactTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ContactTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ContactTitle != value))
            {
                this.OnContactTitleChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ContactTitle = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ContactTitle");
                this.OnContactTitleChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Address", 
     DbType="NVarChar(60)")]
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Address;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Address != value))
            {
                this.OnAddressChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Address = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Address");
                this.OnAddressChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_City", 
    DbType="NVarChar(15)")]
    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return this._City;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._City != value))
            {
                this.OnCityChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._City = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("City");
                this.OnCityChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Region", 
    DbType="NVarChar(15)")]
    public string Region
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Region;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Region != value))
            {
                this.OnRegionChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Region = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Region");
                this.OnRegionChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_PostalCode", 
        DbType="NVarChar(10)")]
    public string PostalCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PostalCode;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._PostalCode != value))
            {
                this.OnPostalCodeChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._PostalCode = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("PostalCode");
                this.OnPostalCodeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Country", 
        DbType="NVarChar(15)")]
    public string Country
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Country;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Country != value))
            {
                this.OnCountryChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Country = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Country");
                this.OnCountryChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Phone", 
  DbType="NVarChar(24)")]
    public string Phone
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Phone;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Phone != value))
            {
                this.OnPhoneChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Phone = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Phone");
                this.OnPhoneChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Fax", 
      DbType="NVarChar(24)")]
    public string Fax
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Fax;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Fax != value))
            {
                this.OnFaxChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Fax = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Fax");
                this.OnFaxChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Image", 
     DbType="NVarChar(50)")]
    public string Image
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Image;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Image != value))
            {
                this.OnImageChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Image = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Image");
                this.OnImageChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new       
     PropertyChangedEventArgs           (propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
 #pragma warning restore 1591
```

Comment: Are you sure you've provided enough code?

Comment: Why are you showing code from the Designer.cs file.. where is the rest of the code where you are trying to return the context to a List where are the method calls..? this is entirely too much code to be putting on SO

Comment: The Visual Studio designer is using some reflection mechanisms to discover the class it can add to the drop down list. You need to make sure the project contains all the needed references, including indirect ones for this to work. Note the web site can work 100% fine without this, so this is not needed to compile and run the site fine, but the VS designer needs it.

Answer (score 0):

If they're not showing up in the GUI, try manually specifying which methods go with which actions.

Eg:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]
```

[More info here](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/390/using-attributes-to-improve-the-quality-and-usability-of-your-code-part-1-decorating-business-objects-for-data-binding).

Comment: I am having the exact same problem a the OP.  I tried adding [DataObjectAttribute] to the class, but it made no difference.  Also, in this statement:      using (var context = new ItemsDataContext())
            {
                return (from c in context.Items
                        select c.ItemID).Distinct().ToList();
            }       
'select' and 'ItemID' are highlighted by the editor as unresolved.  Project builds successfully.  When I try to run, I get "The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' "

Comment: Pretty sure OP's main problem, same as mine, is that the BAL class in the App_Code folder isn't listed at all, much less methods/properties in the class.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure your project type is a `Web` project, otherwise Visual Studio will not consider the `App_Code` folder
2. Make sure you include `System.Data.Linq` as a reference in your `Web.Config` file bz adding the following

> ```
> <assemblies>
>     <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
> </assemblies>
> ```

3. Following is the Web.Config file content. I got the content from the exercise files on the  [Introduction to ASP.NET 4 WebForms](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/aspdotnet-webforms4-intro) course from pluralsight:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See comments here: stackoverflow.com/questions/16170156/

I think adding an assembly ref to web.config solved the problem for me.